# Trust relationship failed for new computer on the domain - Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have a brand new Windows 7 laptop that needs to connect to a domain on Windows Server 2012.  The laptop has not been on the domain before.  When I try to hook the laptop up to the domain I get the error:

"The user could not be added because the following error has occurred: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

I have seen this before and previously rejoined the domain to fix it, however with this laptop I cannot even do that.  I am having the same problem on another new laptop, which makes me think there could be something wrong with the server, but workstations can still logon fine and I have reset a password for a user and that has been ok.  I can ping the domain name and the server name and I have tried with multiple accounts, including the domain administrator to join the domain.  I have even disabled IPv6 in case that might have something to do with it, but still the same problem.

I'm now going round in circles with the whole thing and desperate for answers.  Please help!

Comment: Guessing this question should really be in the Super User or Server Fault area, but my guess is that your image for the laptop (assuming you're using an imaging process that is) is not sysprep'ed. So your workstation boots up with an identical name/SID, which breaks the trust relationship with an existing workstation (potentially) and forces you to rejoin the workstation to the domain (on the new one you're configuring as well). This would not be a server issue, but rather an issue with the image you're using.

Comment: I'm not using an image.  The laptop is a brand new buy from Dell.  We haven't put anything on it yet aside from Notepad++

Comment: Hmm...that is pretty odd. I would still suspect something on the client side, but it's hard to say what it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely it's a firewall issue between the Windows 7 client and the Server. Even if you have other clients that (appear to) log on to the domain fine from the same site.  Use PortQryUI to confirm this. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24009.  Additionally ensure the DNS client settings on the client only use DNS servers that host the AD DNS zone.

If the issue is not resolved, then on the DC, open a Cmd (with admin privileges) and run a DCDiag > DCdiag.txt.  Copy the contents of the DCDiag here for me to review.

Comment: For some reason the answer I posted with the output in was posted before your post.  Hope you see it.

Comment: Use the Answers option when providing an answer to the question, when providing more information to the question, edit the original question.

As the firewall resolved the issue, I would be grateful if you could accept my answer as the answer.  As for the DCDiag, that looks very concerning.  Rerun the DCDiag from the DBKB4C92, if you still receive a failed test Connectivity, create a new post, so myself and others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I uninstalled the firewall software that was running on the laptop and now it has joined the domain and everything is working well.  However, I ran the PortQry program anyway (thanks for providing the link, useful tool) and selected the "Domains and Trusts" predefined service and all seemed ok aside from port 42, which wasn't running on the localhost anyway.

As for the dcdiag, see output below:

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:

Trying to find home server...

Home Server = DBKB4C92

- Identified AD Forest. 
  Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DBKB4C92

```
  Starting test: Connectivity

     The host f9008c03-1537-412a-a81e-e3ce6efbbf45._msdcs.MYDOMAIN.COM

     could not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP,

     server name, etc.

     Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your

     firewall settings.

     ......................... DBKB4C92 failed test Connectivity
```

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DBKB4C92

```
  Skipping all tests, because server DBKB4C92 is not responding to

  directory service requests.
```

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test

     CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test

     CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on : Schema

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on : Configuration

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on : MYDOMAIN

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... MYDOMAIN passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... MYDOMAIN passed test CrossRefValidation
```

Running enterprise tests on : MYDOMAIN.COM

```
  Starting test: LocatorCheck
```